# How do I generate a random num::BigUint?

Tags: rust, bigint

I need a random 256-bit unsigned  number. I discovered that there is the [`RandBigInt`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.0/num_bigint/trait.RandBigInt.html) trait with the method `gen_biguint()`, but I am having a tough time finding an implementation for it.

I tried doing this some time ago for `BigInt`. The crates have been updated since. This is how I am using it to get a `BigUint` now.

```
extern crate num;
extern crate rand;

use num::bigint::{BigInt, BigUint, RandBigInt};

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut n: BigUint = BigUint::default();
    loop {
        let bigUint: Option<BigUint> = rng.gen_bigint(256).to_biguint();
        match bigUint {
            Some(num) => {
                n = num.clone();
                println!("Found the 1st BigUint - {}", num);
                break;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Contents from my **Cargo.toml**

```
num = "0.1.42"
rand = "0.4.2"
```

I am sure there must be some straight-forward way of achieving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the README of `num`:

> The `rand` feature enables randomization traits in `num-bigint` and `num-complex`.

```
[dependencies]
num-bigint = { version = "0.2.0", features = ["rand"] }
rand = "0.5.4"
```

Then you need to use a [`RandomBits`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.0/num_bigint/struct.RandomBits.html) which implements [`rand::Distribution`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.5.4/rand/distributions/trait.Distribution.html):

```
extern crate num_bigint;
extern crate rand;

use num_bigint::{BigInt, BigUint, RandomBits};
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    let signed: BigInt = rng.sample(RandomBits::new(256));
    let unsigned: BigUint = rng.sample(RandomBits::new(256));

    println!("{}, {}", signed, unsigned)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shepmaster's answer was raising a trait bound error in more recent versions of rand. Got this to work:

Cargo.toml

```
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.6"
num-bigint = { version = "0.2.2", features = ["rand"] }
```

main.rs

```rust
use num_bigint::{BigUint, RandBigInt};

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let unsigned: BigUint = rng.gen_biguint(256);
    println!("{}", unsigned);  
}
```