# How can I create a random array between a range of two other arrays?

Tags: random, rust

I need to generate an array of random 20 bytes between a given range of arrays. Since arrays are comparable in Rust, this works:

```
let low = [0u8; 20];
let high = [2u8; 20];
assert_eq!(true, low < high);
assert_eq!(false, low > high);
assert_eq!(true, low == [0u8; 20]);
```

For these bounds:

```
let low: [u8; 20] = [98, 0, 1, 0, 2, 6, 99, 3, 0, 5, 23, 3, 5, 6, 11, 8, 0, 2, 0, 17];
let high: [u8; 20] = [99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
```

These would be a valid result:

```
[98, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

These are not:

```
[98, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

I want to do something like:

```
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let low = [0u8; 20];
    let high = [2u8; 20];
    let value = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(low, high);
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

but I get following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8; 20]: rand::distributions::uniform::SampleUniform` is not satisfied
 --> src\main.rs:6:36
  |
6 |     let value = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(low, high);
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `rand::distributions::uniform::SampleUniform` is not implemented for `[u8; 20]`
```

I tried implementing `SampleUniform` and `UniformSampler` without much success. Is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean with "between given range of arrays"? Do the arrays represent a number? For the `rand` crate, each array is just a sequence of bytes. There is no such concept as the range of values between two arrays

Comment: If you can use a `Vec` instead of an array, I would just do: `let value: Vec<u8> = iter::repeat_with(|| rand::thread_rng().gen_range(low, high)).take(20).collect();`

Comment: @aochagavia - The bounds are just two 160 bit number (big endian). I want to get a random value between these bounds. For example `[1u8;20]` would be a valid result between `[0u8;20]` and `[2u8;20]`.

Comment: I think you need to implement the various `rand` traits. However, you won't be able to do that for `[u8; 20]` because that is not defined in your own crate and neither are the traits. Instead you'd have to create a newtype. e.g. `struct U8x20([u8; 20])` and implement for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat the byte arrays as big integers, use the
[num-bigint](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.2/num_bigint/) crate with the `rand` feature enabled:

```rust
use bigint::{ToBigInt, RandBigInt};

let low = -10000.to_bigint().unwrap();
let high = 10000.to_bigint().unwrap();
let b = rng.gen_bigint_range(&low, &high);
```

You could also use unsigned integers instead of signed. There are methods to convert to and from big endian byte arrays:

- [`from_bytes_be`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.2/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#method.from_bytes_be)
- [`to_bytes_be`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.2/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#method.to_bytes_be)

See also:

- [How do I generate a random num::BigUint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51640381/155423)

Comment: I tried it but getting `no method named ``gen_biguint_range`` found for type ``rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng`` in the current scope`

Comment: does it recommend using a certain trait after the message?

Comment: ```use bigint::{ToBigInt, RandBigInt};
```

Comment: Tried that.. it doesn't work. Also, doesn't recommend any traits. It keeps saying `RandBigInt` is not in the root. I am using rand 0.6.

Comment: You also need to enable the "rand" feature